# Daphne Odora - Silvering leaves

Tags: diseases, leaves

Hi this Daphne odora is growing in a pot in well draining soil in a fairly well protected position, it's spring time. but it's leaves are silvering here are a couple of photo's:
Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be the problem?

[image: Silvering leaves]
[image: Silvering leaves underside]

Thankyou!

Comment: Hi, the picture seems to be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stippling appears to be spider mite.  Look for small webbing under the leaves.
I really can't tell from  your pictures if this is definitely the problem, but it is my best educated guess.

IF you do find spider mite webbing, move it away from the rest of your plants.  Give it a a really good washing, spraying off the bottom and top of each leave with water.   Put is in your shower or use a hose sprayer, but only as much pressure as your shower might have.  You don't want to break the leaves.

After the plant has dried spray with neem oil or the chemical found in neem, Azadirachtin.  One treat will not work.  It will take multiple applications, but follow the directions on the bottle on the intervals between spraying.

Let's say the bottle says you can spray in two week intervals, during that middle week dust it with Diatomaceous Earth.

Both these treatments works and are safe to use.

BTW- The damaged leaves will always look that way, but the plant will eventually shed those deformed leaves.

Comment: Amazing, thankyou for your detailed answer!
There was some webbing, i'll give this a go.